# How to create system user on window server 2003 in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-server-2003

Hi i want to create a system user in window server 2003 active directory for which i use following C# code ,

```
 DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://"+Environment.MachineName+",computer");

            DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(username, "user");

            NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });

            NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test User from .NET"});

            NewUser.CommitChanges();

            DirectoryEntry grp;

            grp = AD.Children.Find("Guests", "group");

            if (grp != null)
            {
                grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() });
            }
```

this code makes user when i run this application locally on visualy studio web engine but when i deploy this application on iis on window server 2003 this will give exception

Exception:

```
General Access Denied Error
```

kindly help me what im doing wrong which permission is required to create user in window server and how we give this perssion. thanks.

Comment: Have you got solution for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace. Utilizing classes from it you can do this in such way:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "MachineName", "AdminUserName", "AdminPassword"))
{
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context, username, password, true);
    user.Description = "Test User from .NET";
    user.Save();

    var guestGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Guests");
    if (guestGroup != null)
    {
        guestGroup.Members.Add(user);
        guestGroup.Save();
    }
}
```

Also, you may configure impersonation on your application and skip all parameters in the PrincipalContext constructor exception the first one if this functionality allowed for administrators only.

Comment: this code also give the same exception:                                                                         General access denied error :